# How can we integrate $\int ds \sqrt{1-\frac{2M}{\sqrt{b^2+s^2}}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I need to find analytical form of the following integral
$$
I = \int ds \sqrt{1-\frac{2M}{\sqrt{b^2+s^2}}}\ ,  \qquad b>2M
$$
where $M$ and $b$ are positive constants.

Comment: I think that a closed form for this integral will involves a complicated combination of elliptic integrals of first, second and third kind. Try symbolic softwares. In practice, better use numerical calculus.

Comment: Introducing new variable $s=b\sinh x$, $ds=b\cosh x dx$ and $\sqrt{b^2+s^2}=b\cosh x$. Finally, we have
$$
I = b \int dx \sqrt{\cosh x\left(\cosh x-\frac{2M}{b}\right)}=b\int dx \sqrt{\left(1+2\sinh^2 x/2\right)\left(\sinh^2 x/2+1-\frac{2M}{b}\right)} 
$$